# Pass an array to a function, reverse it without using the Array.Reverse() method and return the reversed array

Tags: c#

I want to pass an array to a function, reverse it without using the Array.Reverse() method and return the reversed array. I am actually trying to do it without using the temp variable in this case.
Below is my code snippet. Please correct me where I am getting it wrong.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int[] reverse = new int[5];
        reverse = ReverseArray(array, reverse);

        foreach (int item in reverse)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reverse);
        }
    }

    public static int[] ReverseArray(int[] arr, int[] rev)
    {
        int x = arr.Length - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++)
        {
            rev[i] = arr[x];
            x--;
        }
        return rev;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? And why are you putting these additional restrictions on the problem?

Comment: You need to explain what is wrong with your current code. Do you get an error? Does the array not reverse properly? Is there an issue with output to the console?

Comment: Why don't you just use LINQ reverse?

Comment: Not the cause of your problem but if you increase the length of `array`, for example by adding `, 6` to it, your code will break.  I would change `new int[5];` to `new int[array.Length];` to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am actually trying to do it without using the temp variable in this case.

Let's ignore this bit first, and use a temp variable where it makes sense. We can come back to it.

There are a few different ways in which we can deal with the general problem of "reverse an array". We can reverse the array itself in-place, we can create a new array that is the reverse of the array we were given, or we can fill in another array we are given to be the reverse of the first array we were given. Your solution has a mixture of the three, and hence manages to do none of them properly.

To fill in a second array we are given we do not need a temp, as we aren't swapping, and we do not want to stop at a middle point:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int[] reverse = new int[5];
    ReverseArray(array, reverse);

    foreach (int item in reverse)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}

public static void ReverseArray(int[] arr, int[] rev)
{
    int x = arr.Length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++, x--)
    {
        rev[i] = arr[x];
    }
}
```

We've gone through every single element in `arr` and put it in the relevant position in `rev`.

To return a new array we do much the same thing, but creating the new array within the method itself:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int[] reverse = ReverseArray(array);

    foreach (int item in reverse)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}

public static int[] ReverseArray(int[] arr)
{
    int[] rev = new int[arr.Length];
    int x = arr.Length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++, x--)
    {
        rev[i] = arr[x];
    }

    return rev;
}
```

A variant of this doesn't create a new array at all, but just iterates through it, producing an `IEnumerable<int>`. This is faster to return the first result and doesn't use as much memory with large arrays, but re-does the reversing every time it's used, so it varies in how useful it is accordingly:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    IEnumerable<int> reverse = ReverseArray(array);

    foreach (int item in reverse)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<int> ReverseArray(int[] arr)
{
    for (int i = arr.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        yield return arr[i];
    }
}
```

To reverse an array in-place we want to work our way from the outside to the middle swapping elements:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    ReverseArray(array);

    foreach (int item in array)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}

public static void ReverseArray(int[] arr)
{
    int x = arr.Length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++, x--)
    {
        int temp = arr[x];
        arr[x] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

This breaks your arbitrary no-temp-variable rule. We can get around this with a little trick of bit-twiddling, though there's no real value in doing that.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    ReverseArray(array);

    foreach (int item in array)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}

public static void ReverseArray(int[] arr)
{
    int x = arr.Length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++, x--)
    {
        arr[x] ^= arr[i];
        arr[i] ^= arr[x];
        arr[x] ^= arr[i];
    }
}
```

There's really no value in not using a 4-byte temporary variable though.

Answer (score 1):

The `x` might not need to decrement, you can use  `arr.Length - 1 - i` instead of `x` for array index otherwise, you will only revered half array.

```
public static int[] ReverseArray(int[] arr, int[] rev)
{
    int x = arr.Length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++)
    {
        rev[i] = arr[arr.Length - 1 - i];
    }
    return rev;
}
```

and I would only pass one array be for method and you can declare the reverse array in the method.

```
public static int[] ReverseArray(int[] arr)
{
    int[] reverse = new int[arr.Length];
    int x = arr.Length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++)
    {
        reverse[i] = arr[arr.Length - 1 - i];
    }
    return reverse;
}
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uIU7pf)

**Result**

```
5
4
3
2
1
```